# Adding a row in DataTables with pagination enabled and showing the newly added row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery DataTables to dynamically add a row to a table which has pagination enabled.

My DataTable initialisation is as follows:

```
$('#tasksTable').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/admin/gettaskstable",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "Data",
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
    "aoColumns": [
       { "bVisible": false },
       { sWidth: '10em' },
       { sWidth: '15em' },
       { sWidth: '10em' }
    ]
});
```

My code that handles the adding of the row is:

```
$("#addTaskButton").click(function (event) {

    var taskTypeID = $("#taskTypesDropDown").val();
    var taskType = $("#taskTypesDropDown").find("option").filter(":selected").text();
    var taskDescription = $("#taskDescription").val();
    var tasksTable = $("#tasksTable").dataTable();

    /* Sumbit data to the server */
    $.post("/admin/addtask", { 
        taskTypeID: taskTypeID, 
        taskDescription: taskDescription 
    }, function (result) {               

            /* Add row to the datatable */
            var newRow = tasksTable.fnAddData([
                result,
                taskType,
                taskDescription,
                'True'
            ], true);

            /* Display newly added row*/
            var settings = tasksTable.fnSettings();
            tasksTable.fnDisplayRow(tasksTable.fnGetNodes()[newRow[0]]);           

        });
    })
```

I am using the extension fnDisplayRow found here http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api

The problem is that this line which is getting the row returns null:

```
tasksTable.fnGetNodes()[newRow[0]]
```

Looking at the settings.aoData I can see my newly added row but nTr is null as are all the rows that are not displayed due to the pagination. For example if there are 30 records and I'm on the first page which displays 10 records, nTr is null for records 20-30 and any record I add to the end.

I have fnDraw() set true on fnAddData(), how do I get to generate the tr for those records which are not displayed?

Comment: I've got it to work by setting false for the redraw on fnAddData, then using fnPageChange('last') to go to the last page where the record is sitting and thus generating the tr, call fnDraw(), then use fnDisplayRow() to find the row again. This seems like I've gone about it in the wrong way though!

Answer (score 0):

I think the nTr is not created until the row is been displayed, if the row is located on a page that is not displayed the nTr will be null.

I solved this problem going to the page where the row is located before trying to displayed it. I am using the property **aiDisplayMaster** that keeps the sort position for each displayed element and then calculate the page according to the **_iDisplayLength**.

```
var settings = tasksTable.fnSettings(),
    page,
    displayLength = settings._iDisplayLength;

$.each(settings.aiDisplayMaster, function(idx, row){
    if(row === position){
        page = Math.floor(idx / displayLength); 
        // paginate to that page
        settings.oInstance.fnPageChange(page);
        //--nTr should not be null here
    }
});
```

Hope this can help to solve the error, let me know your comments and suggestions about it.